# How to read Log items from MemoryTarget NLog asynchronously

Tags: c#, nlog, asynchronous

I use this example http://nlog-project.org/documentation/v2.0.1/html/T_NLog_Targets_MemoryTarget.htm

and I would like how we can read  `Log` items from `MemoryTarget` **NLog** ***asynchronously*** to populate `RichTextBox` for instance?

```
using System;

 using NLog;
 using NLog.Targets;

 class Example
 {
     static void Main(string[] args)
     {
        MemoryTarget target = new MemoryTarget();
        target.Layout = "${message}";

        NLog.Config.SimpleConfigurator.ConfigureForTargetLogging(target, LogLevel.Debug);

        Logger logger = LogManager.GetLogger("Example");
        logger.Debug("log message");

        foreach (string s in target.Logs)
        {
            Console.Write("logged: {0}", s);
        }

        // Access to target.Logs async.
        // Have I target.Logs.Clear() the Logs when I get all items?
    }
}
```

Any clue?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to create a new thread and pass the `MemoryTarget` to the new trhead.

PS: writing to the `RichTextBox` is already implemented in the [NLog.Windows.Forms package](https://www.nuget.org/packages/NLog.Windows.Forms). See the [official documentation](https://github.com/NLog/NLog.Windows.Forms/wiki/RichTextBoxTarget) how to use.